# Detached Passport

Tags: passports

My Indian Passport is detached from the main part but everything else is intact. I am in Australia at the moment and will be travelling in 15 days within Australia. What do I do?! I am on a student visa in Australia.

[image: Image of the passport detached from its cover]

Comment: If you cannot get a new one promptly I personally would stick it together with super glue until I get back home. Alternatively you can get an emergency passport from the Indian High Commission

Comment: @Sanjana What did you end up doing? If you got a re-issued passport, did you have to get the visa stamped also?

Comment: @ajp super late but Australian visas are electronic-only.

Answer (score 4):

If you dont have any other document that you can use for domestic travel within Australia, please visit the nearest Indian Embassy and highlight the issue.

If you will be in Australia temporarily and will be returning to your country of origin soon, you will anyway have to visit the Indian Embassy as that passport may cause issues (in that the border staff or the airline check in staff may consider that passport as tampered with) while travelling internationally.

A picture of the damage will help.